# AppleScript: How to loop through list of URLs one at a time to open & close a browser window

Tags: curl, applescript, client-side

I'm trying to load a list of URLs in a browser one at a time. I don't care about any output, I just need the page to load, once finished loading completely, change the location to the next URL in the list. I've tried and given up accomplishing this in Automator. I'd use CURL but I don't know enough about passing authentication (several cookies must be present).

Is this possible with a simple ActionScript? Ideally, input would be a txt file with a line for each URL.

**Update! This is working:**

```
set thePath to (path to desktop as Unicode text) & "sites.txt"
set theFile to (open for access file thePath)
set theContent to (read theFile)
close access theFile

set theURLs to every paragraph of theContent

tell application "Safari"
    repeat with theURL in theURLs
        make new document
        set URL of front document to theURL
        delay 1
        repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState" in front document) is "complete")
            delay 1
        end repeat
        close front document
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sets a list of URLs, loads each one, and waits until the document is ready to continue. Note that each URL has to be complete (i.e., `http://cnn.com/` and not `cnn.com`) to load a page this way.

```
set myURLs to {"http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://cnn.com/", "http://nytimes.com/"}

tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    set myDoc to front document
    repeat with myURL in myURLs
        set URL of myDoc to myURL
        -- wait until page is loaded to open new page
        repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState" in front document) is "complete")
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: This is great, but it loads each URL in a new window. Any way to just use one window and change the location of the same window for each URL?

Comment: Updated based on comment, but for some reason this isn't working 100% of the time for me. Try it and post if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah its not working for me yet. It seems like maybe the repeat is ending once a page completes the readystate within the 1 second delay. (so pages that load slow are being changed before loaded completely, then if a page loads quickly it ends the loop) Is there a way to say "while myurls not empty, load first link, when finished loading, remove link from myurls"?

Comment: Hm, not sure what the prob is. Are you getting any specific error, or is it just not loading correctly? Let me know. I'll see if I can figure anything out in the meantime.

Comment: I tried adding a delay before and after the javascript ready check (to visually see if all URLs were being loaded in turn) Also, I'm using diff URLs. Got this error: Safari got an error: Can’t set document \"Untitled\" to item 2 of {\"http://google.com/\", \"http://yahoo.com/\", \"http://bing.com/\"}." number -10006 from document "Untitled"

Comment: This seems to be working:

```tell application "Safari"
 repeat with myURL in myURLs
  make new document
  set URL of front document to myURL
  delay 1
  repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState" in front document) is "complete")
   delay 1
  end repeat
  close front document
 end repeat
end tell

Comment: Glad it's working. If this post helped you out, consider upvoting.